# Application load time is so slow when using many sounds in Soundpool... any substitutions?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

Long story short, I am making a soundboard. Short clips, so by researching, Soundpool seemed like the best option. It has worked out phenomenally for me, except that the overall load time is getting longer and longer. I have many sound clips in there, and I have them all load in the onCreate() in the main activity, in order to remove any further loading time between other activities. As I said, the load time is already long, and I plan on having many more sound clips added in. Is there some sort of substitution that would load faster? I have seen a soundboard that loads a significantly larger amount of sound clips, and the application is almost immediately loaded, and all sounds are immediately ready to play when their buttons are clicked. If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it!!

This is the app that I was talking about, if it would help to see it in action:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cr5315.grump&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jcjUzMTUuZ3J1bXAiXQ..

Answer (score 0):

Don't load them in onCreate-  load them in an AsyncTask that gets launched in onCreate.  That way it will load in the background as your app is running.  You'll just have to add null checks for each sound, or not play sounds until the entire set of sounds is downloaded (use a flag set in the end of your task to check for this).

Comment: Could you provide a short sample of how this should look?